# turning a uniform distribution into a normal distribution

Tags: excel, statistics, uniform, normal-distribution

how do i turn a uniform distribution to a normal distribution
I have Random samples of 2000 numbers between 0 and 1 and I did this for 10 columns

I got the average of all ten columns and put it on the 11 column; 2000X1 matrix
And then created a chart, however it looks like a uniform distribution rather than a normal distribution. why?
http://www.statisticalengineering.com/central_limit_theorem.htm

how do i switch the x and y axis so it looks like an normal distribution

[image]

Comment: How did your create your random samples of 2000 numbers between 0 and 1?

Comment: This looks like a scatterplot of the random values (y) against their row (x). That will not reveal the distribution.  You need to bin the *values* into narrow ranges--try about intervals of width about 0.05 to start with--and count the number of random values falling within each bin.  Plot the counts versus the bin midpoints to represent the histogram.

Answer (score 1):

Update: I'm not sure which goal you have in mind:

- A: to show the slight normality of the values that you get from
  averaging 10 random numbers between 0 and 1?
- B: to obtain a set of random numbers that follow a normal
  distribution (random + normal meaning that the probability of
  obtaining each value is exactly proportional to the probability
  density function of the normal model with mean 0 and standard
  deviation 1)?

If A is your goal, then you just need to make a proper histogram of the values and it will look slightly bell shaped but also have quite a bit of scattering.

If B is your goal, then you can do it easily by just making two columns in Excel. The first column filled with rand() values between 0 and 1, and the second column containing the formula NORM.S.INV() being evaluated with the value contained in the cell to its left.

...

To change numbers that are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 into ANY other distribution, let's just say S, all that needs to be done is to plug those numbers into the inverse of the cumulative distribution function of S.

Since you want the normal distribution, the inverse of the cumulative normal distribution function is the function that you need to plug in your numbers into in order to get a random, normally-distributed range of values.

This function in Excel is called NORM.S.INV()

To make a histogram, you could go to the Excel menu and then Add-Ins / Manage Excel Add-ins / Go / Check the box by Analysis ToolPak / then click on the Data tab in the ribbon.

You will need to make a column containing "Bins" which separate components of the histogram. You could do 0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, etc. through 1. (Tip: Just type 0 and 0.1 into the first two cells, then select those two cells (both must be selected) and then drag the corner down until you reach 1.0.)

Then click on the Data Analysis button in the Data tab, choose Histogram, for the input range select your column containing the averaged numbers, for the Bin Range, choose the bins going from 0 to 1, and click OK. Select the data that is produced, and make a scatter plot from it.

Sorry for trying to give the directions when there is a much clearer tutorial on making a Histogram: http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Histogram-in-Excel

Comment: I think he is basically trying to implement a poor man's normal distribution via the CLT, rather than doing an fancy inverse transform.

Comment: Yes, I agree. From the graph I have no clear picture of what the numbers are. They need to be put into a histogram before we can tell. My guess is that they are just random numbers like rand() between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute a histogram of those Y values, so you count many are say, between .4 and .45, .45 to .5, .5 to .55, etc.  That histogram will look normal.

In one line of Python, this is what your graph will look like.

```
hist([sum(random.random() for i in range(10))/10.0 for y in range(20000)], 100)
```

[image: approximate normal distribution from averaging uniform random numbers]

Comment: Averaging 10 isn't enough to make it look very normal. If he needs to create random values that follow a normal distribution, this is only going to be accurate with an enormous set of data. I have made such histograms before and they are all over the place.

Comment: I think an average of 10 uniform samples is going to look okay.  Sample image included.

Comment: Thanks for the actual picture. What would it look like at 2,000?

Comment: My first answer was based on the subject of the post "turning a uniform distribution into the normal distribution" which has an exact answer, which made me click on it and answer. But this person might be having a different question than it sounded like.